# ConditionalOnMissingBean over Primary?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I've noticed in some of spring libraries that most of the beans are annotated with `@ConditionalOnMissingBean`.

Is there any advantage over not using any condition and make use of `@Primary` in main code, or it is just matter of having less annotations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can think of `@ConditionalOnMissingBean` like a fallback.  This bean will be registered if there is no other bean like it that can be found in the context path.

A `@Primary` bean primarily deals with priority.  A bean annotated with that will be registered *first*, which typically implies that it's the *only* bean that will be used.

Using conditional beans depends on what you're doing.  If you have several services which serve different purposes and should not be wired at the same time, a conditional wiring is perfect for that scenario.  If you only ever have or will only ever need one bean, or you're getting a bean (like a `dataSource` from an upstream library, it's useful to specify the bean you want to wire as the *only* one that should be considered.

Answer (score 6):

The definition for `@Primary` (docs):

> Indicates that a bean should be given preference when multiple
>   candidates are qualified to autowire a single-valued dependency. If
>   exactly one 'primary' bean exists among the candidates, it will be
>   the autowired value.

The definition for `@ConditionalOnMissingBean` (docs):

> Conditional that only matches when the specified bean classes and/or
>   names are not already contained in the bean factory.

***In short:***

`@Primary` -> to enforce,

`@ConditionalOnMissingBean` -> to fallback